# How to see hadoop's heap use?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, heap-memory

I am doing a school work to analyze the use of heap in hadoop. It involves running two versions of a mapreduce program to calculate the median of the length of forum comments: the first one is 'memory-unconscious' and the reduce program handles in memory a list with the length of every comment; the second one is 'memory-conscious' and the reducer uses a very memory-efficient data structure to handle the data.

The purpose is to use both programs to process data of different sizes and watch how the memory usage goes up faster in the first one (until it eventually runs out of memory).

My question is: how can I obtain the heap usage of hadoop or the reduce tasks?

I thouth the counter "Total committed heap usage (bytes)" would cointain this data, but I have found both versions of the program return almost the same values.

Regarding the correctness of the programs, the 'memory-unconscious' one runs out of memory with a large input and fails, while the other one does not and is able to finish.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what memory-conscious data structure you are using(If you give which one then might help), But most of in-memory data structure utilizes virtual memory means is data structure size increases to some extent based on policy extra data element/s will be dump into virtual memory. Hence we does not result in Out-of-memory error. but in case memory-unconscious doesn't do that. In both the cases data structure size will remain same that's why you are getting same size. To get real memory usage by Reducer you can get it by:

New Feature added java 1.5 is `Instrumentation` interface by which you can get objects memory usage(`getObjectSize`). Nice article about it: [LINK](http://java.dzone.com/articles/estimating-java-object-sizes)

```
/* Returns the amount of free memory in the Java Virtual Machine. Calling the gc method may result in increasing the value returned by freeMemory.*/
long freeMemory = Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory()


/* Returns the maximum amount of memory that the Java virtual machine will attempt to use. If there is no inherent limit then the value Long.MAX_VALUE will be returned. */
long maximumMemory = Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory();


/* Returns the total amount of memory in the Java virtual machine. The value returned by this method may vary over time, depending on the host environment.
Note that the amount of memory required to hold an object of any given type may be implementation-dependent. */
long totalMemory = Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory()
```